# Rails authority apparent inconsistency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify, authority-gem

I am using the gems authority and rolify to manage user permissions on a set of subjects.
Each subject can be seen by a user only if the user has the `:admin` role for that subject.
Code in the view:

```
   <% if (current_user.has_role? :admin, @subject) %>
        ADMIN
    <% end %>

    <% if @subject.readable_by?(current_user)%>

    #some other code

    <% end %>
```

Code in the authorizer:

```
class SubjectAuthorizer < ApplicationAuthorizer
  # can the user view the subject?
  def self.readable_by?(user)
    user.has_role? :admin, @subject
  end

end
```

My problem is that the ADMIN part is displayed, but not the rest of the page. However, the two if conditions should have the same truth value. Can anyone spot a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@subject` is not available in the Authorizer. You need to use `resource` instead.